# pycharm using a remote interpreter ImportError: No Module named error

Tags: pycharm, python-import, remote-server

I have a project folder with sub folders named F, with files MDN.py and NN_Layers.py, FFN with FFN.py and Util with Data.py and Util.py

My code works on a local interpreter.

In MDN.py I get an error when trying to import a function from Util.Data and from F.NN_Layers.

In FFN.py I can import from a function in Util.Util but not from Util.Data or from F.NN_Layers.

I don't understand why this works locally and why I can do the same kind of import from Util.Util but not Util.Data.

If I move all the imported code to MDN.py it runs fine so it has to do with the project structure.

On the server I have the code mapped to the same git checkout.  I have pycharm set up to snyc the files automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I figured it out.  I have to manually sync the files first otherwise they won't be uploaded.  I could import from Util.Util because I made an edit in that file which caused an automatic upload.